# Qual estrutura de pasta pra o projeto de dll em .net framework que vou jogar no projeto principal

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, console

Tenho uma solução vs2017 com um projeto principal que ira utilizar uma projeto dll como referência.

Criei as pastas model, negocio e repositorio no projeto dll
Projeto principal uso a dll na classe principal.

O que vai em cada pasta da dll?

> ```
> model
>  -Pessoa
>  -Ipessoa
> Negocio
>  ? - Preciso deste??
>  ?
> Repositorio
>  -Repositorio - class
>  -IRepositorio - interface
> ```

Consigo usar normalmente, mas o que me falta para usar a pasta negócio?

Criar uma classe soh para disponibilizar? Ou usar o repositorio direto?

Comment: Repositorio vai seu  banco estruturação mapeamento, model acessa os dados do banco , negocio crio eu que deve ser estrutura a onde você faz a parte logicia de acesso  de uma olha em DDD que deve ser o que está procurando, Domain Design é muito intressante e amplo

Comment: Obrigado darei uma olhada!